# Sync data between two remotely placed servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, records

I have two data servers which are placed remotely in different locations. One server is SQL Server 2008 R2 and the other one is SQL Azure.

SQL Server contains more than 50000000 records and I want to sync that data into the SQL Azure server.

What are the best ways to do so that we did not face following problems

1. Data loss
2. Duplications or data redundancy
3. Delays

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks marc_s for editting :

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Data Sync by installing the sync agent on your SQL Server 2008 R2 machine and point the agent to your SQL Azure database.

Check this link for all the details http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/

Additionally, you can use an SSIS job on the SQL Server to copy the data to your SQL Azure database.

Comment: Thanks sabbour for your consideration